# Does the number 1,23571113... has been studied before?

Tags: prime-numbers

I just can't get this number out of my head. It's a number that has the decimal digits composed by all the prime numbers.

The first digit is not important, it can be 0,2357... or 1,2357...

Does any mathematician has studied this number? Is it transcendental? I guess I can prove it's not a normal number. Where can I find more about it?

Comment: 1 isn't a prime number

Comment: smarandache studies this sort of thing

Comment: The number is called Copeland–Erdős constant, and it has been studied before.

Comment: and it is a normal number by the way

Comment: I thought Benford's law would make it not normal.  and there is this http://www.nature.com/news/peculiar-pattern-found-in-random-prime-numbers-1.19550 ... anyway, thx Loreno

Comment: Most primes have over a billion digits, so neither the first digit nor the last digit has much of an effect, and asymptotically the first and last digits have no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Copeland–Erdős constant is the concatenation of "0." with the base 10 representations of the prime numbers in order. Its value is approximately
0.235711131719232931374143… (sequence A033308 in the OEIS).

In base 10, the constant is a normal number, a fact proven by Arthur Herbert Copeland and Paul Erdős in 1946 (hence the name of the constant).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_constant

thx to Loreno Heer